# How to use setimmutable and loadimmutable in pure yul code?

Tags: solidity

I would like to learn how to use setimmutable and loadimmutable in Yul to set immutable variables that are gas efficient to retrieve in the contract.

A sample code of how to use setimmutable and loadimmutable, using the object notation would be great!

Answer (score 0):

So essentially how immutable works in both regular Solidity and pure Yul is the compiler creates 32 byte [placeholders](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/yul.html#setimmutable-loadimmutable) in the runtime bytecode (deployed contract code) for all the times we use the immutable variables.

The placeholders are automatically created by the compiler whenever the immutable variable(s) are used in the runtime bytecode. If we define an immutable in the constructor but never use that immutable variable, then no placeholders will be created, and the immutable value will simply be pushed onto the stack and then popped off again during constructor execution.

In Solidity we would achieve defining and using an immutable variable simply with the following:

```
contract A {
    uint256 immutable internal x = 9;

    function returnImmutable() external pure returns (uint256) {
        return x;
    }
}
```

So on deployment, the runtime bytecode would have 1 placeholder within the `returnImmutable()` function section. The runtime bytecode would be copied from ROM to memory using `CODECOPY` opcode. The placeholder of 32 bytes of 0 would then be overwritten with `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009` in memory and then the finalized runtime bytecode would be returned from memory in order to deploy the contract.

With Yul we follow the same process, except now we have:

```
object "A" {
    // constructor
    code {
        datacopy(0, dataoffset("RuntimeCode"), datasize("RuntimeCode")) // CODECOPY
        setimmutable(0, "x", 9)  // uint256 immutable internal x = 9;
        return(0, datasize("RuntimeCode"))
    }

    // Deployed code
    object "RuntimeCode" {
        code {
            if iszero(iszero(callvalue())) {    // Revert if ether sent
                revert(0, 0)
            }
            let selector := shr(0xe0, calldataload(0))
            switch selector
            case 0x335173c0 {  // 'returnImmutable()' func sig
                let value := loadimmutable("x")
                mstore(0, value)
                return(0, 0x20)
            }
            default {
                revert(0, 0)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This Yul is basically equivalent to the above Solidity, where `loadimmutable("x")` is telling the compiler to create 1 placeholder within the `0x335173c0` function. Within the constructor `setimmutable(0, "x", 9)` is telling the compiler to overwrite the placeholder with value `9`. Note the offset (first arg in `setimmutable`) should be `0`, because that is the offset **relative to the placeholder**. So if you have an offset of `0x20` then the value of `9` will be placed at the placeholder + 1 word -> so will create an additional word to store the `9` instead of overwriting the original placeholder

You can paste this Yul into [evm.codes](https://www.evm.codes/playground?fork=cancun) to deploy the contract, then copy runtime bytecode with calldata `0x335173c0` to prove the above works as intended.